# How to use a trigger to decrease a count and a computation on APEX to ensure that the count doesn't go below 0

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I want to make a trigger function that decreases a student's token count everytime a teacher make a complaint about a student. I currently don't have a table that keeps track of when a students count changes, i only have a table which shows their initial count. Can i make a display on apex that shows this intial count and has this count decrease whenever a teacher submits a form on apex that is a complaint about that student? (Teachers should also be able to ad tokens to a students account for good behaviour).

Also this token count cannot go below 0 so im guessing this will just be a computation on the token count that ensures that the token value cannot be less than 0 (or at least i imagine this can be done).

Im kind of new to triggers and all i know on them so far is how to make a sequence and a trigger that inserts a new primary key value when a new row is to be made on the database. Im not used to triggers that decrease counts so im not sure how this would work.

As mentioned i also dont have a table that keeps track of students token counts changing and im not sure if i need a table in my database on this or if apex can somehow just display the value for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you really use MySQL? Or is it Oracle?

Comment: Hi, i thought mysql was another name for oracle sql. Ive changed the tags now.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like Stack Overflow's *up & downvoting*.

As there's a table which contains student's data and one of columns is `NUMBER_OF_VOTES`, then teachers would have two buttons: `P1_UPVOTE` and `P1_DOWNVOTE` (or whatever you want to name them).

Pushing `P1_UPVOTE` would do

```
update student s set
  s.number_of_votes := s.number_of_votes + 1
where s.student_id = :P1_STUDENT_ID;
```

Similarly, pushing `P2_DOWNVOTE` would

```
update student s set
  s.number_of_votes := s.number_of_votes - 1
where s.student_id = :P1_STUDENT_ID
  and s.number_of_votes > 0;      --> so that student wouldn't have negative votes
```

That should do it, I guess.

Comment: Thanks, so im guessing there is no need for a trigger function here then. Also where would i be entering this query in Apex? Would it be a dynamic action on the teachers making a complaint? And how would i display this counter? Would i list the current non-changing vote count and will that script above automatically change its display value?

Comment: UPDATEs would be *processes* (executed when appropriate buttons are pressed, i.e. the page submitted). Dynamic action is another option. Once the page is submitted, it refreshes and displays counter's current value.

Comment: Hi, ive tried making a process to do this but im having trouble. I cant seem to find a way to make sure that this works when my complaint form is submitted as i dont see an option for the process to run on submission of another forum on a different

Comment: To add on, ive made some progress with getting the counter to decrease by 1 now whenever a teacher submits a complaint. However, the >0 condition is not working. When a teacher makes a complaint on a student with 0 tokens the complaint still goes through and the students token count remains at 0 when instead an error message should pop up on the teachers screen that states that they cannot make a complaint anymore